# Is this a perfect problem for the factory pattern?

Tags: java, spring, factory-pattern

I want to design the file storage part of my application with some flexibility, so one can store files in either S3 or on the web server's hard drive.

I also want this to be flexible on a per user basis, so in their user settings they can choose if they want their files stored in S3 or on the servers file system.

I am thinking of something like this:

```
IFileStorage fs = FileStorageFactory.Instance(userSettings);
```

Then I would have a method that looks like:

```
public static IFileStorage Instance(UserSettings setting)
{
     if(setting == UserSettings.S3)
         return new S3FileStorage();
}
```

Does this make sense?  (I'm a c# programmer but I will be doing this in Java)

I am using Spring, but I don't think DI will be used here since the implementation changes on a per user basis.

Comment: Ok, you said you are a C# developer, but please, please, please use java code conventions when you write java code. I can't stand uppercase method names and the I-prefix for interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Factory and Dependency Injection aren't mutually exclusive. Spring has the so-called [factory-method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) which produces beans. You can pass arguments to the factory-method, and it can be either static or non-static.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That seems appropriate. You're returning a *particular instance* of a class to the user, so as long as their requirements don't change halfway through the program, then the factory is appropriate (otherwise I'd recommend a [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern)

Comment: The strategy provides a *dynamic* behavioural change. I'm not sure if you need that capability ?